# How to group data in a column based on a column value and analyze the max or min on that?

Tags: python, pandas

I have columns NAME,ID, SEX, AGE, GAMES, TEAM, SPORT, YEAR, where each column doesnt have any null value.
Now I want to find Which team has brought the most number of female and male players.
I have written this code -
`rf.groupby('Team')['Sex'].value_counts()` 
and this outputs to -
[image]

now here inturn I want to find the team which has maximum num of male and female players individually.. can anyone help me with this.
"Which team has brought the most number of female and male players." - this is the question. can you let me know if I want to change the first statement groupby only that I have mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
rf.groupby('Team')['Sex'].value_counts().unstack().idxmax()
```

---

```
print (rf)
    Team Sex
0  team1   M
1  team1   M
2  team1   M
3  team1   F
4  team2   M
5  team3   F
6  team3   F
7  team2   M
8  team1   M
```

Another idea is use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `idxmax`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(rf['Team'], rf['Sex'])
print (df)
Sex    F  M
Team       
team1  1  4
team2  0  2
team3  2  0

s = pd.crosstab(rf['Team'], rf['Sex']).idxmax()
print (s)
Sex
F    team3
M    team1
dtype: object
```

For scalars:

```
print (s['F'])
print (s['M'])
```

If need both info - `max` and team by `max` use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(rf['Team'], rf['Sex']).agg(['max','idxmax'])
print (df1)
            F      M
max         2      4
idxmax  team3  team1
```

If need scalars:

```
print (df1.loc['idxmax','F'])
print (df1.loc['idxmax','M'])

print (df1.loc['max','F'])
print (df1.loc['max','M'])
```